# iphone Addressbook caller blocking

Tags: ios7, abaddressbook

Since iOS7 it's possible to block a caller when she/he calls your phone...

Is it possible to change this setting from within an app?

The idea is having an app that lets the user block people temporarily from calling them. Another option would be to send them directly to voicemail or send them a (predefined) text-message if they're calling.

I don't need code, just a hint whether this would be possible and which settings I'd have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible from within app. Apple hasn't provided any such API. [Check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203)